# Error sorting list using Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to sort list of objects based on my name property. So I created a comparator and i notice it is not getting sorted. Please advise if any error in using this.

```
List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
Country country1 = new Country("TEST1","Washington");
Country country2 = new Country ("TEST10", New Delhi");
Country country3= new Country ("TEST9", London");
countryList.add(country1);
countryList.add(country2);

Collections.sort(countryList,new Comparator<Country>() {
            public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
});
```

I am getting out put as which should be other way.

```
    TEST1 : Washington
    TEST10 : New Delhi
    TEST9 : London
```

Expected is

```
    TEST1 : Washington
    TEST9 : London
    TEST10 : New Delhi
```

Comment: Your code isn't right.

Comment: Please mention what do u mean by `getName()`? is that mentioned by "TEST1" or "Washington"

Comment: You are sorting the list alphabetically. `TEST10` comes before `TEST9` because of this - because `1` comes before `9`. You have to modify the implementation of your `compare()` method to order the elements the way you want.

Comment: It will compare character by character, so it is printing TEST10 first and then TEST9

Comment: Thank you all. Understood the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to sort by Name here. But names are TEST1, TEST10 and TEST9. When you compare this, you will get the order alphabetically:

```
TEST1
TEST10
TEST9
```

You can try below code:

```
Collections.sort(countryList,new Comparator<Country>() {
                    public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                        if (o1.getName().length() > o2.getName().length()) return 1;
                        if (o1.getName().length() < o2.getName().length()) return -1;

                        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                    }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Alphabetically TEST10 comes before TEST9

Answer (score 2):

The `String` `compareTo` use `lexicographically` to compare *string*, but your logic need compare the ***length*** of string:

```
Collections.sort(countryList,new Comparator<Country>() {
            public int compare(Country o1, Country o2) {
                if (o1.getName().length() > o2.getName().length()) return 1;
                if (o1.getName().length() < o2.getName().length()) return -1;

                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
});
```